# Calculate percentage function

Tags: javascript

Struggling to get the desired results, code to test
The first two functions work, but the third one for the discount does not.
Depending on the number I put in the input field it should apply a discount up to 20% max on increments of 5,(so 1 = 5%, 2 = 10%, etc). No matter the value I put in the input field (deadline) value is stuck in applying the 20% discount. Full bit for testing:

```js
//Dropdown list calculation//
var service_prices = new Array();
service_prices["0"] = 0;
service_prices["1500"] = 1500;
service_prices["4000"] = 4000;
service_prices["8000"] = 8000;

function getServicePrice() {
  var serviceOptionPrice = 0;
  var form = document.forms["formulario"];
  var selectedOption = form.querySelector("#servicePrice");
  if (service_prices[selectedOption.value]) {
    serviceOptionPrice = service_prices[selectedOption.value];
  }
  return serviceOptionPrice;
}

//checkbox calculation//

function extraPrices() {
  var extraPrices = 0;
  var form = document.forms["formulario"];
  var selectedBoxes = form.querySelectorAll("#selectedBox");
  selectedBoxes.forEach((box) => {
    if (box.checked == true) {
      extraPrices += 400;
    }
  });

  return extraPrices;
}
//discount calc
const getDiscountPercent = (months) => (months < 4 ? months * 0.05 : 0.2);

const getTotal = (servicePrice, extraPrice, months) => {
  const disTotal = servicePrice + extraPrice;
  const discountPercent = getDiscountPercent(months);

  return disTotal - disTotal * discountPercent;
};

//total final calc//

function Total() {
  var finalPrice = (getServicePrice() + extraPrices()) * getDiscountPercent();
  document.getElementById("result").value = "€" + finalPrice;
}
```

```html
<form action="" id="formulario" name="formulario">
  <p> Type of Service
  </p>
  <select name="serviço" id="servicePrice" onchange="Total()">
    <option value="none">Select a service
    </option>
    <option value="1500">1500€
    </option>
    <option value="4000">4000€
    </option>
    <option value="8000">8000€
    </option>
  </select>
  <br>
  <p>Deadline (months)
  </p> 
  <input type="number" class="InStyle" id="months" name="months" onkeydown="Total()">
  <br>
  <!--checkbox-->
  <h1>DESIRED EXTRAS
  </h1>
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="selectedBox" value="4" id="selectedBox" onclick="Total()"> Who we are
  <input type="checkbox" name="selectedBox" value="5" id="selectedBox" onclick="Total()"> Where we are
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="selectedBox" value="6" id="selectedBox" onclick="Total()"> Gun Gallery
  <input type="checkbox" name="selectedBox" value="7" id="selectedBox" onclick="Total()"> eCommerce
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="selectedBox" value="8" id="selectedBox" onclick="Total()"> Internal Mangement
  <input type="checkbox" name="selectedBox" value="9" id="selectedBox" onclick="Total()"> News
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="selectedBox" value="9" id="selectedBox" onclick="Total()"> Social Network
  <br> 
  <br> 
  <br>
  <!--result-->
  <h1>Estimated Total
  </h1>
  <input type="text" class="InStyle" disabled id="result">
</form>
```

Comment: Looks like `month` argument for `getDiscountPercent()` call is always empty inside `function Total()`. You need to figure out how to pass the value of input fields to it.

Comment: in which function do are getting wrong output?

Comment: @RahulMohanty
in the //discount calc one

The others run fine but I can't get this one to get a value from my input field and apply a discount depending on it to the total final value

Comment: @ArtyomNeustroev Then if I'm not mistaken I should make it so the discount function before, grabs a value from the input field?

Comment: Yep, anywhere you call `getDiscountPercent()` should be provided with a `months` value for which you want to calculate the discount amount

Comment: @ArtyomNeustroev Sometimes I can't believe how something so obvious can fly by my eyes, jesus christ. Seems that all that's left for it to be up and running properly is to make the function not trigger when the value is 0, but atleast this is already real good progress

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not passing the months amount to `getDiscountPercent` function, neither taking months value from the input and also I advice you to use `onChange` event on month input .

```
function Total() {
  var months = parseInt(document.querySelector('#months').value);
  var finalPrice = (getServicePrice() + extraPrices()) * getDiscountPercent(months);
  document.getElementById("result").value = "€" + finalPrice;
}
```

Comment: when put like that, ok I see it now. It does work! Now all that's left is for me to find out how to make it ignore triggeriing the function when the input field is 0

Comment: You can add conditionals inside any function you want. Just evaluate "months" value.